# Prolog, Is it possible to use variable to call clause?

Tags: prolog

I have the following problem in Prolog.
I have rules

```
foo(L).
boo(L).
doo(L).
```

which all return a different list,
and a rule: bar(X), which returns "foo" or "boo" or "doo" as X.
Now I want call the appropriate function by saying something like:

```
bar(X),
X().
```

This does not work, is there any similar way to do this?
Otherwise I have to add a rapidly increasing amount of code, because I will declare more rules like foo(L) in the future.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, @AndersonGreen but I disagree. The question you linked refers to sb. expecting Prolog returning values other than true and false and is lacking knowledge how to handle prolog variables.

Comment: You want to use `call(X)`. There is no need for parentheses to cause a goal to be evaluated in Prolog. If you need to pass parameters to the predicate, provide them as additional arguments to `call`, i.e. instead of `X(foo, bar)` which does not work, use `call(X, foo, bar)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog there is the `=../2` operator which works like: `foo(bar) =.. [foo, bar]`
Use this in combination with `call/1` and it works. Sometimes the following works as well:

```
foo(L).
boo(L).
doo(L).

bar(X).
Goal =.. [X, L].
Goal.   % If this does not work, use call(Goal).
```

Comment: `=../2` is a **standard** predicate that exists in virtually all Prolog systems. But, as pointed out in other comments, the also standard `call/N` construct means that often you don't need to use the `=../2` predicate.